# What is a Compact way to Refer to a Set of Non-Contiguous Rows?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code seems inelegant and wasteful. Is there a more compact notation for referencing all those rows?

```
Sub HideEBRedData()
'un/hide EIRP Budget rows with redundant path data
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set EIRPBudget = Sheets("EIRP Budget")

With EIRPBudget
    .Rows(29).Hidden = Not .Rows(29).Hidden
    .Rows(30).Hidden = Not .Rows(30).Hidden
    .Rows(50).Hidden = Not .Rows(50).Hidden
    .Rows(51).Hidden = Not .Rows(51).Hidden
    .Rows(54).Hidden = Not .Rows(54).Hidden
    .Rows(55).Hidden = Not .Rows(55).Hidden
    .Rows(65).Hidden = Not .Rows(65).Hidden
    .Rows(66).Hidden = Not .Rows(66).Hidden
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Simoco provided the answer I was looking for. Here it is:

```
Sub HideEBRedData()
'un/hide EIRP Budget rows with redundant path data
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim r As Variant

Set EIRPBudget = Sheets("EIRP Budget")

For Each r In Array(29, 30, 50, 51, 54, 55, 65, 66)
    EIRPBudget.Rows(r).Hidden = Not EIRPBudget.Rows(r).Hidden
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: if you have many rows to hide/unhide, use loop, but not sure there is a more elegant way.

Comment: @simoco, loop is no good because the row numbers do not necessarily follow a pattern.

Comment: you could use `For Each r in Array(29,30,50,..)`

Comment: @Simico, yes that is exactly what I was looking for. I suspected there was a better way, but forgot about arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this code is what OP looking for:

```
Sub HideEBRedData()
    Dim r As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set EIRPBudget = Sheets("EIRP Budget")
    For Each r In Array(29, 30, 50, 51, 54, 55, 65, 66)
        EIRPBudget.Rows(r).Hidden = Not EIRPBudget.Rows(r).Hidden
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub FlipHidden()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A29,A30,A50,A51,A54,A55,A65,A66")
    r.EntireRow.Hidden = Not r.EntireRow.Hidden
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

This macro will work if all rows are visible when the macro is run.

Comment: actually, it's not working as expected. If row 29 is visible - _all_ rows became hidden, and vice versa, if row 29 is hidden - _all_ rows became visible

Comment: @Simico, good point. I find it still works if I run the sub twice. Not ideal.

Comment: Hi simoco......start with an empty sheet with all rows visible.....first run of the macro leaves row#28 and row#31 visible and row#29 and row#30 hidden.............re-run restores visibility to all rows.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, ok, we start with empty sheet. Hide row #30 (which is in range `A29,A30,A50,A51,A54,A55,A65,A66`). OP expect that after running macro row #30 would be visible, and rows `29, 50, 51, 54, 55, 65, 66` hidden. However you code will hide all rows `29, 30, 50, 51, 54, 55, 65, 66` (including row # 30)

Comment: @simoco......You are correct..........my code will flip the hidden state of rows properly **only** if they all start the same way (hidden or un-hidden)........otherwise a loop is needed.